# useEffect rendering multiple times even when data is not changing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

This useEffect is rendering one time if dependency array is empty but multiple times if i put folderRef in dependency array. I want to render the component only when I add or delete some folder. Please Help

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect , useRef } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import FolderData from "./FolderData";

function ShowFolder(props) {
  const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);
  const folderRef = useRef(collection(db, "folders"));

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(folderRef.current);
      const folderData = data.docs.map((doc) => {
        return { id: doc.id, data: doc.data() };
      });
      console.log(folderData);
      setFolders(folderData);
    };
    getData();
  }, [folderRef]);

  return (
    <div className="container md:px-4 mx-auto py-10">
      <div className="md:grid lg:grid-cols-6 md:grid-cols-3 mlg:grid-cols-3 md:gap-10 space-y-6 md:space-y-0 px-1 md:px-0 mx-auto">
        {folders.map((folder) => {
          return (
            <div key={folder.id}>
              {folder.data.userId === props.userId && (
                <div>
                  <FolderData key={folder.id} folder={folder} />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ShowFolder;
```

Comment: It seems that there is a relationship between `setFolders` and `folderRef`. Can you provide more code? Especially the `setFolders` function? And it would be great to have a working example.

Comment: @RenéLink `setFolders` is likely the state updater function for the `folderData` state. I think the relationship you are referring to would be between the dependency `folderRef` and the `folderData` state since updating the state is what would trigger a rerender.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's hard to say what the code we can't see is doing.

Comment: `  const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);
  const folderRef = collection(db, "folders");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(folderRef)
    const getData = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(folderRef);
      const folderData = data.docs.map((doc) => {
        return { id: doc.id, data: doc.data() };
      });
      console.log(folderData);
      setFolders(folderData);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);  `         this is what i m using

Comment: When you put the `folderRef` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` it means that on every render react checks if the dependency changed. If so the `useEffect` is invoked. Since you update the `folders` state inside the `useEffect` it triggers a rerender. Thus I guess `collection(db, "folders")`  does return a different value each or multiple times that causes the `useEffect` to execute and thus another rerender. And so on...

Comment: i have edited the question. there u can find full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redeclare `folderRef` each render cycle, so if you include it in the `useEffect` hook's dependency array it will trigger render looping.

If you don't refer to `folderRef` anywhere else in the component then move it *into* the `useEffect` hook callback to remove it as an external dependnecy.

```
const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const folderRef = collection(db, "folders");

  const getData = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(folderRef);
    const folderData = data.docs.map((doc) => {
      return { id: doc.id, data: doc.data() };
    });
    console.log(folderData);
    setFolders(folderData);
  };

  getData();
}, []);
```

Or store it in a React ref so it can be safely referred to as a stable reference.

```
const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);
const folderRef = useRef(collection(db, "folders"));

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(folderRef.current);
    const folderData = data.docs.map((doc) => {
      return { id: doc.id, data: doc.data() };
    });
    console.log(folderData);
    setFolders(folderData);
  };

  getData();
}, [folderRef]);
```

#### Update

I've gathered that you are updating the `folders` collection elsewhere in your app and want this component to "listen" for these changes. For this you can implement an `onSnapshot` listener.

It may look similar to the following:

```
const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
    collection(db, "folders"),
    (snapshot) => {
      const folderData = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        folderData.push({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        });
      });
      setFolders(folderData);
    },
  );

  // Return cleanup function to stop listening to changes
  // on component unmount
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Comment: none of it is working. when i add folder the component does not rerender.  `  const folderAddHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await db.collection("folders").add({
      title: folderName,
      userId: props.userId,
    });
    console.log('added')
    setFolderName("");`   this is my add folder function.

Comment: @VaishaliAggarwal Can you post the complete component code to your question so we can see all that it's trying to do, and when/how it's trying to do it?

Comment: I have edited the question. you can find full code there

Comment: @VaishaliAggarwal Where do you add a folder? I don't see that `folderAddHandler` function. Are you trying to update a firebase collection and want this component to pick up the changes?

Comment: yes exactly. The folderAddHandler function is in other component. do i share that too?

Comment: @VaishaliAggarwal For this I believe you want a snapshot listener. You seem to be using the recent version of firebase/firestore (*version 9?*). Would you like me to attempt an example solution for you?

Comment: it would be very kind of you if you could do it. I am a newbie in this field and hence dont know much about it.

Comment: @VaishaliAggarwal Sure thing. Please see update section in my answer. I'm not well versed in firebase collections, especially the newest modular system, but I think it's close to what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I think most Probably your useState function is like

```
const[folderRef , setFolders]=useState(Your Initial Value);
```

if this is the case then when ever you perform

```
useEffect(() => {
setFolder(Setting Anything Here)

....


},[folderRef])
```

React starts an infinity loop coz every time you use setFolder the FolderRef gets updated and the useEffect is forced to run again and it won't Stop .

use something like

```
const[folderRef , setFolders]=useState(Your Initial Value);
const[isLoading, setIsLoading]=useState(true);


useEffect(() => {
setFolder(Setting Anything Here)
setIsLoading(false)
....


},[])

...


return (
{ isLoading ? "Run the code you wanna run " : null  }
)
```